# Blueprinter not returning model defined methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

Using blueprinter gem is only returning the column defined attributes. Any attempt to return instance methods or renaming associations is not working.

Fields/associations defined in the blueprint are not being returned in the JSON, as well as any method defined in the class.

For ex.

```rb
class UserBlueprint < BlueprinterBase
  identifier :slug, name: :id

  fields :first_name, :last_name, :full_name, :formatted_dob

  association :locations, name: :location, blueprint: LocationBlueprint do |user, _options|
    user.locations.first
  end
end
```

The fields that are defined in the schema are `:slug, :first_name, :last_name` and those get returned fine. But the `:formatted_dob` and `:full_name` are defined as instance methods on the model. These are not getting returned. Also, the association defined in the blueprint is not being returned either.

I am calling the blueprint through a helper method, but I don't think that should be an issue. I have never had this problem until today and can't seem to find out why.

```rb
# helper method definition
def serialized_resource(resource, blueprint, options = {})
  JSON.parse(blueprint.render(resource, options))
end

# called in the controller with...
render json: { users: serialized_resource(User.all, UserBlueprint) }
```

And the return is:

```
"users": [
  {
    "id": "45hsadfknadsf98hasn",
    "first_name": "FirstName",
    "last_name": "LastName"
  },
  ...
]
```

Thank you for any help/suggestions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting input in the issue I raised there, it had to do with the conditional rendering. I was initiall getting undefined method errors if there wasn't an object returned from a query. So I used the global conditional rendering. This is the fix from the issue in the repo.
`config.unless = ->(field_name, obj, _options) { obj.public_send(field_name).nil? }`

It wasn't returning the instance methods defined because the instance methods don't respond to bracket notation on the object. So using the above code snippet, instead of the one in their docs fixed this issue.

[Blueprinter Repo Issue](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter/issues/229)